# mostrar usuarios con los que se tiene una conversación y su ultimo mensaje

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, handlebars

[image: Esto es lo que me devuelve el codigo]

//hola gente, como dice el titulo quiero mostrar datos de las personas con quien se tiene una conversacion y su ultimo mensaje, estoy usando un motor de plantillas handlebars, mongoose para consultas a base de datos mongodb y nodejs como servidor, les dejo lo que hice

```
var conversaciones = await mensajes.find({
    $or: [{
      $and: [{de: req.user._id}]
    }, {
      $and: [{para:  req.user._id}]
    }]
  }); //aqui estoy trayendo las conversacion
```

//aqui el hbs

```
{{#if conver}}
    {{#each conver}}
        <div class="boxing-message" id="message_perfil">
    <div class="boxing-header border-bottom h-25 text-center">
        <img src="/img/{{avatar}}" alt="" srcset=""> <span>{{nombre}}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content-message border-bottom text-center">
        <span> 
            {{mensaje}}
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
    {{/each}}
{{else}}
<div class="container-fluid mt-3 pt-5">
        <div class="card-header m-3 p-3">
            <p class="d-inline">
                Aun no tienes conversaciones.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

//lo que hace esto es mostrarme todos las mismas casillas del mismo usuario, lo que busco es que me aparezca una sola casilla para cada usuario y que se vea el ultimo mensaje de dicha conversacion

//les dejo mis modelo de mensajes

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const mensajes = new Schema({

   de: {type: String, required: true},
   para: {type: String, required: true},
   mensaje: {type: String, required: true},
   visto: {type: String, default: '0'},
   leido: {type: String, defaul: '0'},
   avatar: {type: String, required: true },
   nombre:{type: String, required: true},
   add_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
});

module.exports = model('mensajes', mensajes);
```

//este es mi modelo de usuario

```
   const usuariosModel = new Schema({

   nombre: {type: String, required: true},
   apellido: {type: String, required: true},
   usuario: {type: String, required: true, unique: true, typeKey: '$type'},
   email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
   nacimiento: {type: String, required: true},
   sexo: {type: String, required: true},
   password: {type: String, required: true},
   longitud: {type: String, default: '0'},
   latitud: {type: String, default: '0'},
   aviso: {type: String, default: '0'},
   registro: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
   avatar: {type: String, default: 'user-4.png'},
   socketId: {type: String, default: '0'}

});
```

//aqui busco los datos y lo envio al inicio de la app

```
var conver = await mensajes.find({
    $or: [{
      $and: [{de: req.user._id}]
    }, {
      $and: [{para:  req.user._id}]
    }]
  });


        res.render('inicio', {
            title: ' inicio',
            //personas con las que hay una conversacion
            conver
        });
```

//se puede ver claramente que aparecen los mismo usuarios y los mensajes, yo lo que quiero es que se vea una sola casilla de ese usuario y solamente el ultimo mensaje

un ejemplo claro lo puedes ver en tu celular, mas específicamente en la aplicación whatsapp, tengo que hacer un proyecto para la universidad y no puedo encontrar la vuelta, en la aplicación aparecen todas las personas con las que se tiene una conversación y su ultimo mensaje de esa conversación

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes el código del back el cual se encarga de rellenar las variables para pasárselas al html del handlebars y posteriormente hacer el compilado?

Comment: Modifique y lo adjunte a lo ultimo, es eso lo que me pedias?

Comment: Creo que el problema radica en la consulta. Ya que estas buscando las conversaciones que estén implícitas any usuarios. Mas no estas filtrando las ultima conversación de dichos usuarios.

Answer (score 1):

**Editado**: En base a lo que hablamos por el chat, necesitas mostrar el último mensaje de cada conversación. He preparado una query con aggregation framework que encaja con el resultado que buscas.

Lo primero filtramos por todas las conversaciones del usuario. A continuación creamos un campo (dePara) con el que emplearemos para agrupar y diferenciar las conversaciones. Una conversación es la misma si el usuario está en "de" o "para".

Para poder agrupar correctamente el array "dePara" ordenamos por nombre, si "de" es menor alfabeticamente lo agregamos antes que "para". De este modo podemos agrupar por el array "dePara"

Por último, sacamos la fecha del último mensaje y así en el últimpo stage podemos obtener el documento del último mensaje.

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "$and": [{"de": "enzo"}]
        }, 
        {
          "$and": [{"para":  "enzo"}]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "dePara": { "$cond": { "if": { "$lt":["$de", "$para"]}, "then": ['$de', '$para'], "else": ['$para', '$de'] } }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$dePara",
      "mensajes": {"$addToSet": {"mensaje": "$mensaje", "add_at": "$add_at"}},
      "mensajeUltimo": {"$last": "$add_at"}
    }
  },
  {
      "$addFields": {
          "ultimoMensajeFiltrado": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                {
                    "$filter": {
                        "input": "$mensajes",
                        "as": "msgs",
                        "cond": { "$eq": ['$$msgs.add_at', '$mensajeUltimo']}
                    }
                },
                0
              ]
          }
      } 
  }
  ]
```

Te dejo un enlace para que veas el resultado del código: https://play.db-ai.co/m/Xo48zYOtowAByoPn/edit?key=sQ83YG6qa6A

Comment: sinceramente tu aporte no me ayuda en nada

Comment: ¿Inspeccionaste que vale tu objeto "conver" que es lo que le estás pasando al template para ver si realmente se le está pasando el valor correcto al motor de handlebars?

Comment: el objeto `conver` no trae lo que yo quiero, ese es mi problema, lo unico que estoy haciendo es traer los chats donde el usuarios esta involucrado, pero cuando hay mas de un mensaje se generan muchas casillas del mismo usuario y eso es lo que no quiero, quiero traer todos los chats donde el usuario sea participe pero que se muestren todos, no que se muestre siempre el mismo o los mismos, quiero mostrar uno por chat inluido el ultimo mensaje de esa conversacion

Comment: Vale, entonces si puedes modificar tu pregunta y yo modificaré mi respuesta para poder ayudarte en lo máximo posible.

Comment: ok, adjunte una imagen para que puedas ver lo que me esta devolviendo el código con los datos compilados mediante handlebars

Comment: Vale creo que he entendido. Tu quieres mostrar todas las conversaciones en las que el usuario está involucrado pero mostrar solamente el último mensaje de cada conversación y que cada fila sea el último mensaje de cada conversación independiente. ¿Correcto? Si es así confirmame y te preparo un ejemplo. También que modifiques la pregunta para que sea más concisa y pueda llegar a más gente con el mismo problema. Un saludo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106248/discussion-between-gudari-and-enzo).

Comment: vale, te lo agradecería

Answer (score 0):

Aquí presento mi solución al problema.

```
var conver = await mensajes.find(
  // filter {
    $or: [{de: req.user._id}, {para:  req.user._id}]
  },
  null, //projection
  // options
  {
    sort: {
      add_at: -1
    }
  }
);

res.render('inicio', {
  title: ' inicio',
  //personas con las que hay una conversacion
  conver
});
```

Espero que te sirva de algo, Suerte!.